# ReactJs Render Value (Array of Objects) of Object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

```
{
    "pendingShareholder": [
        [{
                "id": 5351,
                "userName": "iverson",
                "firstName": "Allen",
                "lastName": "Iverson",
                "password": "$2a$10$20ILdapdX6u8G1nH2jIr6upiKY04LCxD9yjHKUHRhUfpuG1w1ywd2",
                "contact": "97801671",
                "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
                "roles": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "ROLE_SHAREHOLDER"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": 5951,
                "userName": "rosgeller",
                "firstName": "Ros",
                "lastName": "Geller",
                "password": "$2a$10$Udrju2Tj6mKGJRZA3d2GFer6kfSI988xI1/R50s.XmrHcIN1IJxoO",
                "contact": "90908899",
                "email": "peter.sou@gmail.com",
                "roles": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "ROLE_SHAREHOLDER"
                }]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Hi all

I have the above object. As you can see it is an object, with one key ("pendingShareholder"). The value of this key is an array inside an array (with objects inside).

I need to return this out in ReactJS. Using React Hooks here. I can't seem to do it no matter what  :(
Can anyone help me. I am going nuts here

Thanks in advance!

```
const adminStateObject = useSelector((state) => state.admin11111);`

return (
    <div className="adminmaincontent">
      <h2>Pending Approval Users</h2>
      <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {Object.keys(adminStateObject).map((key, i) => (
          <tbody key={uuid()}>
            {adminStateObject[key].map((key2, i2) => (
              <tr key={uuid()}>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.id}</td>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.userName}</td>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.firstName}</td>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.lastName}</td>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.contact}</td>
                <td key={uuid()}>{key2.email}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: is using `uuid() ` to generate a key is good idea? it will create a new key on every render which defeats the entire purpose of using keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have too many `map` operations going on. You need *one* that iterates over your nested array.

And as Gulam mentions in their comment using uuid on every `tbody`, `tr`, and `td` is overkill. Just add the object id as the row key.

```js
function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>UserName</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.pendingShareholder[0].map(obj => (
          <tr key={obj.id}>
            <td>{obj.id}</td>
            <td>{obj.userName}</td>
            <td>{obj.firstName}</td>
            <td>{obj.lastName}</td>
            <td>{obj.contact}</td>
            <td>{obj.email}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const data = {pendingShareholder:[[{id:5351,userName:"iverson",firstName:"Allen",lastName:"Iverson",password:"$2a$10$20ILdapdX6u8G1nH2jIr6upiKY04LCxD9yjHKUHRhUfpuG1w1ywd2",contact:"97801671",email:"john.doe@gmail.com",roles:[{id:3,name:"ROLE_SHAREHOLDER"}]},{id:5951,userName:"rosgeller",firstName:"Ros",lastName:"Geller",password:"$2a$10$Udrju2Tj6mKGJRZA3d2GFer6kfSI988xI1/R50s.XmrHcIN1IJxoO",contact:"90908899",email:"peter.sou@gmail.com",roles:[{id:3,name:"ROLE_SHAREHOLDER"}]}]]};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems to be working. I can see two rows now, which equats to the two users. BUT... I can't see the id, userName, firstName etc. It is just blank... Any idea why is this happening? Could it be because I am actually having an array of 2 objects inside a single array?

Comment: An update. With Andy's answer, when I try to render out {obj} it gives me the index of the array... Basically, 0 and 1... so it seem like another round of mapping is needed?

Comment: I got the key wrong which might have caused the whole thing to not render. I've updated my answer with a working example. I hope that helps.

Comment: many thanks for the help! you are a life save. Perfect answer! Thank you Gulam for the advise too :) I am a beginner and still learning. Cheers!

Comment: I've been at this 20 years, Ewan. We're always learning. Glad to help.